# Why can't the signUp and login methods be called when using bmob?

Tags: android, api, android-studio, jar

This question is about why I have successfully implemented dependencies and imported, but some methods can't be called successfully.

```
import cn.bmob.v3.Bmob;
import cn.bmob.v3.exception.BmobException;
import cn.bmob.v3.listener.SaveListener;


    theUserImformation user =new theUserImformation();
    user.setAccount(the_account);
    user.setPassword(the_password);

    user.login(this,new SaveListener(){
        @Override
        public void done(Object o, BmobException e) {

        }
    });
```

android Stuido reported an error
**can't resolve method**

the method signUp also cant be calling.

I am implementing the registration and login functions of an app. I search for information on google, I find other programmers can successfully calling these methods, but I can't. I have successfully referenced the corresponding package actually.

why does this happen? Can you give me some direction to solve the problem? thanks!

I still remember a similar situation when I called the okhttp3 library. part of the method could not be called

I just learned about Android development, so I dont konw why?can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! I have dealt with the problem by myself.

Because my theUserImformation class has extended the wrong superclass.
Misunderstand the development documentation examples.

I ended up looking through the bomb SDK class library documentation. I find the "signUp" and "login" methods in  "cn.bmob.v3.BmobUser" class. So I solved the problem successfully.